# Flask WTForms not capturing information from fields

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask WTForms to submit a form capturing information about a new school subject. The POST request is going through, but it's not capturing the information from the form fields.

I get this message in my terminal:

```
ERROR:  (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "grade" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (15, , null).

[SQL: INSERT INTO subjects (name, grade) VALUES (%(name)s, %(grade)s) RETURNING subjects.id]
[parameters: {'name': '', 'grade': None}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2020 11:57:29] "POST /api/subjects/create HTTP/1.1" 422 -
```

My CURL requests also return empty data fields. 
Would it be better to join the GET and POST request endpoints for creating a new subject? I've separated the POST request into a separate endpoint handling requests for API use, while the GET is for the frontend.

app.py

```
@app.route('/api/subjects/create', methods=['POST'])
    # @requires_auth('post:subjects')
    def create_subject_api():
        '''
        Handles API POST requests for creating new subject. Returns JSON.
        '''
        body = request.get_json()
        form = SubjectForm(request.form)

        name = form.name.data
        grade = form.grade.data

        subject = Subject(
                name=name, grade=grade
            )

        try:
            subject.insert()
            redirect(create_subject_api)

        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR: ', str(e))
            abort(422)

        flash(f'{subject.grade}:{subject.name} successfully created!')

        return jsonify({
            'success': True,
            'subject': subject.format()
        })
```

forms.py

```
class SubjectForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(
        'Name', [DataRequired()]
    )
    grade = SelectField(
        'Grade', [DataRequired()],
        coerce=int, choices=[
            ('7', '7'),
            ('8', '8'),
            ('9', '9'),
            ('10', '10'),
            ('11', '11'),
            ('12', '12')
        ])
```

new_subject.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>New Subject</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <h3 class="form-heading">List a new subject</h3>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="grade">Grade</label>
            {{ form.grade.label }} {{ form.grade }}
        </div>
        <button type="button" value="Create Subject" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="submitSubject()">
            Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
    <script>

        function submitSubject() {
            let name = document.getElementById("name");
            let grade = document.getElementById("grade");

            let data = {
                "name": name,
                "grade": grade
            }

            fetch(`${window.location.origin}/api/subjects/create`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((myJson) => {
                    if (myJson['success'] == true) {
                        window.location.href = '/subjects';
                    }
                });

        }

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't comment so, I will write it as an answer, what happens if you try to print put your grade and name data before you create the database object

You could try changing the submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create Subject">
```

As it seems like the form either doesn't pass validation or it doesn't get submitted

One way to check if it has validated is to see if it passes through

```
If form.validate_on_submit()
```

Comment: Comes up as None

Comment: Ok so, try chamging the button to something like this:<input type="submit" value="Create Subject">

Comment: Thanks, have tried all this and it's now throwing up a 405 error as the submit button is not redirecting to /api/subjects/create

Comment: Oh, what happens if the only thing you change from how it was before is only changing the type from button to submit?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't able to help.

Comment: No worries! Thanks anyway!